# Invalid Token when using Octal numbers

Tags: python, syntax, python-3.x, octal

I'm a beginner in python and I'm trying to use a octal number in my script, but when I try it, it returns me that error:

```
>>> a = 010
SyntaxError: invalid token (<pyshell#0>, line 1)
>>> 01
SyntaxError: invalid token (<pyshell#1>, line 1)
```

There's something wrong with my code? I'm using Python3 (and reading a python 2.2 book)

Comment: There may be something wrong with your Python installation or the shell you are using. Try the same thing at http://shell.appspot.com and see if you get the same errors.

Comment: @Gene: As explained elsewhere, octals must be written with prefix '0o' in Python3, not just '0' as in Python 2, which now yields an error. (*Sigh*)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Try `0o10`, may be because of python 3, or pyshell itself.

PEP says,

> octal literals must now be specified
>   with a leading "0o" or "0O" instead of
>   "0";

http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3127/

Comment: I wish every language required this for octal numbers; how stupid was using a lead 0.  Now if we can just get support for 0sNNN (for sexagesimal) and put base-64 numbers into our code.

Comment: Think of the possibilities for magic constants... no longer being constrained to `0xdeadbeef`, etc. :o

Comment: @Rafael I think you mean "0o", not "Oo" :)

Comment: Is there any method that works in both Py3 and Py2.7?

Comment: Yes. Using the Python3 syntax works for both Python2 and Python3.

Comment: Which also means that, finally, in Python3, `0` is no longer octal ([unlike in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895522/is-0-a-decimal-literal-or-an-octal-literal)).

Comment: But they do allow 00 without error, which is inconsistent with throwing an error for cases 01, ..., 07 where the leading 0 does not make any difference. (And why "finally", as if that was an achievement? Why should 0 not be octal? There's not any reason to prefer 0 to be base 10 rather than base 8 or base 2...)