# Why is 00100 = 64 in python?

Tags: python, int

Why, like in the following python code, does `00100` equal `64`?

```
>>> i = 00100
>>> i
64
>>> type(00100)
<type 'int'>
>>> str(00100)
'64'
>>> str("00100")
'00100'
>>> int(str("00100"))
100
>>>
```

Comment: I do not know Python but looks like `i = 00100` is interpreted as Octal. so, `1*8^2+0+0 = 64`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

its an octal value because of leading zeros

http://www.translatorscafe.com/cafe/units-converter/numbers/calculator/octal-to-decimal/

^calculator (hard to summarize)

Comment: As an aside, note that in Python 3 this would be a syntax error, because the syntax for octal literals has changed.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837874/invalid-token-when-using-octal-numbers

Answer (score 2):

In Python (and other languages too) when a number begin with 0 is interpreted as an [octal number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal).

Comment: @n00b32 Hey, it happens. Sometimes it's because someone was typing the same time as you, or looking up a link, or sometimes they think they can answer the question more clearly or with extra information. You often get more upvotes if you win the race, but that's not everything.

Comment: i know, i dont downvote if some one answers within 5 minutes... i just remind ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's octal. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal

1 is 01, 2 is 02, ..., 7 is 07, 8 is 10 (yes!), 9 is 011, etc.

Comment: same answer 3rd (4 with comment) time