# What does this mean "0100644" mean in Python 2?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I tried to find out what this is in Python 2:

```
>>> x=0100644
>>> x
33188
>>> x=100644
>>> x
100644
```

As you can see with or without the leading '0', x value is different in Python 2. I am not largely familiar with Python 2 types. Can you help show me what `0100644` is in python 2?

Comment: sounds like octal. The value agrees.

Comment: A better duplicate would be: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243968/why-is-00100-64-in-python/5243986#5243986

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 2.x anything with a leading `0` is octal, `0b` is binary, `0x` is hex.

```
>>> 0b01010   # binary
10

>>> 01010   # octal
520

>>> 0x01010  # hex
4112

>>> 1010  # decimal
1010
```

Comment: Why did you answer _and_ closevote? Closevoting should suffice aplenty.

Comment: Because I saw the duplicate, and it only seemed to discuss octal, so I thought I'd show the other interpreted types just for completeness.

Comment: If the question is truly a duplicate (and not just similar), you can provide an answer on the duplicate question.