# Understanding str_pad() with leading zeros

Tags: php, octal

I'm trying to build a php function and discovered some weird behavior and I can't even formulate a proper question, so if anyone can explain what is going on, I would appreciate it.

I'm working with a set of numbers with leading zeros, and its important that they be maintained, but users almost never input leading zeros. So I use this:

```
$x = 123;
$n = 5;
$x = str_pad((int)$x,$n,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);
echo $x;
```

and, as desired, this gets me 00123.

The weird stuff happens when I tested for a user inputting a zero before their number

```
$x = 0123;
$n = 5;
$x = str_pad((int)$x,$n,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);
echo $x;
```

This returns 00083. Same thing happens if a user were to input 00123.

That result has me completely bewildered. Thanks in advance for any explanation of what's going on here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Integer literals starting with `0` are interpreted **base 8**. Your second `$x` has the value 83. [See the manual on integers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) for details.

The `intval()` function lets you specify the base if you're reading a user string.

If we're talking about literals, in PHP the literal `0` is decimal, while in [C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895522/is-0-a-decimal-literal-or-an-octal-literal) it is octal. It's the little differences that make life fun.

Comment: I'll look into keeping user input base 10. Now I know what to research, thanks a ton!

Comment: Well, the [`intval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) function lets you specify the base if you're reading a user string. I was just talking about literals.