# Using C am I right in thinking that literals beginning with multiple zeros are considered octal?

Tags: c, literals, octal

In the following C code are octal literals used for all these defines? Even if they start with multiple zeros?

```
#define TCL_REG_BASIC       000000  /* BREs (convenience). */
#define TCL_REG_EXTENDED    000001  /* EREs. */
#define TCL_REG_ADVF        000002  /* Advanced features in EREs. */
#define TCL_REG_ADVANCED    000003  /* AREs (which are also EREs). */
#define TCL_REG_QUOTE       000004  /* No special characters, none. */
#define TCL_REG_NOCASE      000010  /* Ignore case. */
#define TCL_REG_NOSUB       000020  /* Don't care about subexpressions. */
#define TCL_REG_EXPANDED    000040  /* Expanded format, white space & comments. */
#define TCL_REG_NLSTOP      000100  /* \n doesn't match . or [^ ] */
#define TCL_REG_NLANCH      000200  /* ^ matches after \n, $ before. */
#define TCL_REG_NEWLINE     000300  /* Newlines are line terminators. */
#define TCL_REG_CANMATCH    001000  /* Report details on partial/limited * matches. */
```

Comment: Yes, that's correct, though it only takes the one leading zero.

Comment: **especially** if they start with multiple zeros ;) (hex literals start with 0x)

Comment: I just wondered why so many leading zeros, lol.

Comment: The author is probably trying to hint at the width of the bitfield. And wants them to all line up nicely

Comment: What Tim said. This kind of thing is pretty standard (used all over the place in windows headers).

Comment: Idea for an esoteric programming language: Make numbers with one leading zero octal, two leading zeros decimal again, three leading zeros dozenal, four leading zeros base-14, five leading zeros hexadecimal, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From C Standard, 6.4.4.1 Paragraph 3:

> An octal constant consists of the preﬁx 0 optionally followed by a sequence of the digits 0 through 7 only

Comment: When I posted my answer your's was not here!

Comment: @haccks I removed it when I saw that paulsm4 had already answered, but then someone asked me to add it back... Sorry for the confusion. :P

Answer (score 4):

Yes You are right.

### C11, 6.4.4.1 Integer constants:

> An octal constant consists of the prefix **0** optionally followed by a sequence of the
> digits **0** through **7** only.

Comment: Out of curiosity what disallows decimals literals with leading zeroes? E.g. 08 is a syntax error as far as GCC and MSVC is concerned.

Comment: @doynax; Since when `8` comes to the octal representation of a number? And why compiler should not give the warning? I suggest you to read number system.

Comment: I was just curious what the rule identifying 08 as an invalid octal number rather than a proper decimal literal might be since you seemed to have the standard handy. No real reason, just the inner lawyer in me wanting to pick holes in any formal definitions.

Comment: @doynax the same section 6.4.4.1 of the standard specifically defines a decimal constant as starting with a non-zero decimal digit.

Comment: @Nigel Harper: Damn. And I suppose the sequence of 0-7 digits here may be empty, thus covering the "0" case as a (very common) octal literal

Comment: I am pissed off by downvoting without any explanation/comment. This is cowardice.

Comment: @doynax Exactly -  the "optionally followed" bit in the standard quote  means that a bare 0 is technically a valid octal constant.

Comment: @doynax; Here is the complete para: `A decimal constant begins with a nonzero digit and consists of a sequence of decimal
digits. An octal constant consists of the prefix 0 optionally followed by a sequence of the
digits 0 through 7 only. A hexadecimal constant consists of the prefix 0x or 0X followed
by a sequence of the decimal digits and the letters a (or A) through f (or F) with values
10 through 15 respectively.` Which clearly suggest that a decimal number can't begins with `0`. Continued........

Comment: @doynax; .....This means that [a bare `0` is not a decimal integer but an octal integer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6895543/2455888).

Comment: @haccks: Indeed, and Nigel concurs. Thankfully octal numbers have no other properties compared to decimal ones (aside from unsigned promotion) and are thus indistinguishable in this case as near as I can tell

Comment: @doynax; I commented regarding your comment:`I was just curious what the rule identifying 08 as an invalid octal number rather than a proper decimal literal might be since you seemed to have the standard handy. No real reason, just the inner lawyer in me wanting to pick holes in any formal definitions`

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

> http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/constants/
>
> In addition to decimal numbers (those that most of us use every day),
>   C++ allows the use of octal numbers (base 8) and hexadecimal numbers
>   (base 16) as literal constants. For octal literals, the digits are
>   preceded with a 0 (zero) character. And for hexadecimal, they are
>   preceded by the characters 0x (zero, x). For example, the following
>   literal constants are all equivalent to each other:

```
75         // decimal
0113       // octal
0x4b       // hexadecimal
```

Comment: Technically the question is about C, but thankfully C and C++ are the same in this regard

Answer (score 0):

OP's examples are all octal as they begin with a `0`.  Multiple leading zeros or the presence of an 8 or 9 does not change it away from being octal.  An 8 or 9 should case an error.

---

FYI: Some additional occurrences (though maybe not a literal) in C where decimal, octal and hexadecimal interpretation occur.

Although not a literal, in a format string for `printf()`, specifiers like `"%016llx"` are not an octal 016 width, but a flag '0' and a decimal value of `16`.

With `printf()`, output using specifier `"%a"`, the output is in the style "[−]0xh.hhhh p±d," where the significand is in hexadecimal and the exponent is in decimal.

In escape sequences there is no decimal specification.  Some samples follow:

```
\' \" \? \\ \a \b \f \n \r \t \v
\0   (octal)
\01   (octal)
\012   (octal)
\0123   (bad - only up to 3)
\x0 (hexadecimal)
\x01 (hexadecimal)
\x012 (hexadecimal)
\x0123 (hexadecimal)
\x01234… (hexadecimal)
\u1234 (hexadecimal)
\U00012345 (hexadecimal)
```