# The Powers of 10

Tags: c

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>

  #define SIZEOF(arr) (sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]))
  #define PrintInt(expr) printf("%s:%d\n",#expr,(expr))

  int main()
  {
      /* The powers of 10 */
      int pot[] = {
          0001,
          0010,
          0100,
          1000
      };
      int i;

      for(i=0;i<SIZEOF(pot);i++)
          PrintInt(pot[i]);
      return 0;
  }
```

The output of the following code is

> pot[i]:1
>   pot[i]:8
>   pot[i]:64
>   pot[i]:1000

why does it give such output??`

Comment: Because that's what the output of that code is. Any particular question?

Comment: You are printing octals (base 8).

Comment: Powers of 2 are not powers of 10.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: One of them is!

Comment: `LENGTHOF` would be a clearer name than `SIZEOF`.

Comment: 0100 -> 1000 are in different bases

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Prefixing a numeric literal in C with a 0 digit will output it in Octal, which is a base 8 numeric system.

Oct(1) = Dec(1)

Oct(10) = Dec(8)

Oct(100) = Dec(64)

That's where your numbers are coming from.

FYI, Hexadecimal literals are prefixed with 0x and binary literals are prefixed with 0b (IIRC)

**Edit:** To actually answer your question, just remove the leading zeroes from the numbers and it should give you the desired output.

Comment: `0b` for binary literals is non-standard. (Interestingly, `0` is an octal literal; there is no decimal integer literal whose value is zero.)

Comment: @KeithThompson - That is an intersting point about 0! Never thought about it that way.

Comment: @KeithThompson Interesting, are we sure that isn't `00` the octal zero?

Comment: @DSquare: What do you mean by *the* octal zero? Both `0` and `00` (as well as `000` and `0000`, etc.) are octal integer constants with the value zero.

Comment: @KeithThompson Could we call `00` (and `0...0`) an octal literal for 0 and `0` the decimal literal for 0? Since the first 0 might not actually be parsed and used just as a flag and thus `0` not having the "octal prefix" because it can't be the prefix of *nothing*.

Comment: Apparently not http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895522/is-0-a-decimal-literal-or-an-octal-literal

Comment: @DSquare: No. The C syntax for integer constants is unambiguous; all octal constants start with the character `0`, and all decimal constants start with one of the characters `1` through `9`.. `0` and `00` are both octal constants. (`0` happens to have the same value that it would have *if* the syntax treated it as a decimal constant, but it doesn't.) It rarely *matters* whether `0` is octal or decimal, but the simple fact is that it's octal. See [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.4.4.1.

Comment: @Keith: it may be noted that not all integer constants that start with `0` are *therefore* octal: `0x` is the prefix for hexadecimal. (Fortunately, the standard is clear on that: `0` is *the* prefix for octal, and `0x` is *the* prefix for hex.)

Answer (score 2):

Number literals which start with a zero are interpreted as being in *octal* – base 8.  So the first three numbers are octal 1, 10 and 100 (which are 1, 8 and 64 in base-10); the last number is base 10.

Answer (score -1):

Based on how your constants are defined, and how your question is worded, I think you want hex.  Prefix your values with "0x":

`int pot[] = {
    0x0001,
    0x0010,
    0x0100,
    0x1000
;`

Comment: What makes you think that? the title is **The Powers of 10**

Comment: Sorry, I was just working with code where what was intended to be bit flags was defined as such.  I've upvoted to answer octal answer above