# Is 0 an octal or a decimal in C?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, literals, octal

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895522/is-0-a-decimal-literal-or-an-octal-literal). It's octal in C++ and decimal in Java. But no description about C?

Is it going to make any difference if 0 is octal or decimal? This is the question asked by my interviewer. I said no and I explained that it is always 0 regardless whether it is octal or decimal.

Then he asked why is it considered as octal in C++ and decimal in Java. I said it's the standard. Please let me know what is it in C? Will it make any difference? Why are they different in different standards?

Comment: It doesn't matter. It is zero in octal, decimal, binary, base 42...

Comment: Ok @juanchopanza. Why is it different in different standards? what is it in C?

Comment: It's different in different standards because it happened to be easier to write the standard that way. It has no practical meaning.

Comment: @user3801433 The "why" is simply "because the standard authors wrote it that way". Since it *really doesn't matter*, I don't think it's worth trying to "get right" or care much about. The bits will be the same in either case, which is what matters.

Comment: @juanchopanza: For your lack of faith, Captain Blackbeard awards you zero pieces-of-eight.

Comment: @unwind In the implementation, you're absolutely right.  Since OP mentions an an interviewer, this could still be a good question along the lines of, "So OP, say there's some edge case with strange behavior.  How would you go about finding out whether it's specified or not?"  The interviewer might have a secret checklist to see what approaches the interviewee takes: "(i) tests in several implementations; (ii) looks at spec (ii.a) seems to be familiar with reading specs; ...", etc.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor "Post it at SO" !

Comment: @Jongware, Read my description and check my link. Same link i have referred. It doesnt say about C standards

Comment: The C standard specifies only observable behaviour, and whether `0` is octal or decimal is not observable. So I'd say it's unspecified. (No matter what the grammar says, if your compiler treats `0` as decimal, it can still be a conforming implementation.)

Comment: Given that C++ is backward compatible with C, there is no reason why it should differ between the two languages.

Comment: @JanHudec This is a bit off topic, but C++ isn't backwards compatible with C. `int class = 5;`. I believe Objective-C is though.

Comment: @DavidYoung: Well, it's "almost" backwards compatible for a _useful_ value of "almost".

Comment: A numeric literal beginning with `0` is either octal or hex.  If there is an `x` immediately after the first `0` then it's hex.  If the first `0` is followed only by other digits then it's octal.  If the numeric literal begins with any other digit it's decimal.  This is true for both C and C++.

Comment: It is neither.  It is simply zero.

Comment: 0 seems to be the `NULL` of mathematics.  It violates many basic rules, results in unexpected or ambiguous cases, and edge cases.  Fun stuff!  Great question!

Comment: I am curious to know answers of "Will it make any difference? Why are they different in different standards?" ..

Comment: @Amit - will it make a difference? Yes, it could: (a simple purely mathematical example) `0 + 4 + 4` would give you 8 in decimal, and 10 in octal. And there could be a whole manner of strange situations that lead to a calculation that approximates the example - you could call `++` on a variable 8 times in a loop and if the start is 0 in octal, you would get 10. And you might not even spot the problem - consider looping and fetching `arr[myVar++]` and your termination is at, say, `10` - since you're not going out of bounds, you would get only 8 items out of it and skip index 8 and 9.

Comment: @Vld: no it doesn't work that way. Once compiled, the machine code doesn't even know or care whether an int is octal or decimal.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

It makes little difference, but formally the integer constant `0` is octal in C. From the C99 and C11 standards, **6.4.4.1 Integer constants**

> *integer-constant*:
>       *decimal-constant* *integer-suffix<sub>opt</sub>*
>       *octal-constant* *integer-suffix<sub>opt</sub>*
>       *hexadecimal-constant* *integer-suffix<sub>opt</sub>*
>
> *decimal-constant*:
>       *nonzero-digit*
>       *decimal-constant* *digit*
>
> *octal-constant*:
>       `0`
>       *octal-constant* *octal-digit*
>
> *hexadecimal-constant*:
>       ...
>       ...

Comment: @juanchopanza "Will it make any difference? Why are they different in different standards?" are still unanswered. Please share if you have any information

Comment: @juanchopanza Since it's octal, does that not mean that certain compilers (I'm thinking for example of avr-gcc for microcontrollers) can optimize "0" into a single byte? Whereas if it was decimal, perhaps it would be the same size as an int?

Comment: @MikeS It wouldn't make  difference. The literal is still of type `int`. The compiler can do whatever the standard allows it, regardless of the base of the literal.

Answer (score 59):

Octal.

> #### C11  §6.4.4.1 Integer constants
>
> ```
> octal-constant:
>     0
>     octal-constant octal-digit
> ```

And this is true since [C89 §3.1.3.2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#3.1.3.2).

Answer (score 29):

> *Then he asked why is it considered as octal in C++ and decimal in Java*

For sake of completeness, worth mentioning Java specs as well. From [Java Language Specification 3.10.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1):

> ```
> DecimalNumeral:
>     0
>     NonZeroDigit Digitsopt
>     NonZeroDigit Underscores Digits
> ```
>
> A decimal numeral is either the single ASCII digit 0, representing the integer zero, or consists of an ASCII digit from 1 to 9 optionally followed by one or more ASCII digits from 0 to 9 interspersed with underscores, representing a positive integer.

> ```
> OctalNumeral:
>     0 OctalDigits
>     0 Underscores OctalDigits
> ```
>
> An octal numeral consists of an ASCII digit 0 followed by one or more of the ASCII digits 0 through 7 interspersed with underscores, and can represent a positive, zero, or negative integer.

As you can see, a bare `0` is considered as *decimal*.
Whereas any (non-empty) sequence of digits preceded by `0` is considered as *octal*.

Interestingly enough, from that grammar:

- `0` is decimal
- *but* `00` is octal

Comment: Interesting. So it is considered as octal also in java!!

Comment: @user3801433 _"So it is considered as octal also in java"_ Not exactly: from that grammar, a bare `0` is considered as `DecimalNumeral`. But `00` is considered as `OctalNumeral`...

Answer (score 10):

From the C Standard (6.4.4.1 Integer constants)

```
octal-constant:
0
octal-constant octal-digit
```

In fact there is no any difference for zero because zero is a common digit for octal, decimal and hexadecimal numbers. It has meaning only when a number has other digits apart from the single (leading) zero.

Take into account that there are no such integral types as decimal, octal or hexadecimal.

Comment: Even there is no "hexadecimal" type, a constant which expresses a particular value in hex may be a different type from one which expresses the same value in decimal.  For example, if `int` is 16 bits, then `0x8000` will be of type `unsigned int` but `32768` will be of type `long`.  I don't think any such issues are meaningful for a constant zero, but for larger values they certainly are.

Answer (score 10):

It's an octal. See section `6.4.4.1 Integer constants` of the N1570 draft:

```
      integer-constant:
            decimal-constant integer-suffixopt
            octal-constant integer-suffixopt
            hexadecimal-constant integer-suffixopt
      decimal-constant:
            nonzero-digit
            decimal-constant digit
      octal-constant:
            0
            octal-constant octal-digit
      hexadecimal-constant:
            hexadecimal-prefix hexadecimal-digit
            hexadecimal-constant hexadecimal-digit
      hexadecimal-prefix: one of
            0x   0X
      nonzero-digit: one of
            1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
      octal-digit: one of
            0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
      hexadecimal-digit: one of
            0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
            a   b   c   d   e   f
            A   B   C   D   E   F
      integer-suffix:
            unsigned-suffix long-suffixopt
            unsigned-suffix long-long-suffix
            long-suffix unsigned-suffixopt
            long-long-suffix unsigned-suffixopt
      unsigned-suffix: one of
            u   U
      long-suffix: one of
            l   L
      long-long-suffix: one of
            ll   LL
```

Also:

> 3. A decimal constant begins with a nonzero digit and consists of a sequence of decimal digits. An octal constant consists of the prefix 0 optionally followed by a sequence of the digits 0 through 7 only. A hexadecimal constant consists of the prefix 0x or 0X followed by a sequence of the decimal digits and the letters a (or A) through f (or F) with values 10 through 15 respectively.

Comment: Your list doesn't include the terminator `digit`, which is required to fully specify `decimal-constant`.

Comment: @arootbeer While you are true, it is not needed here as the key point is that `0` is listed explicitly under `octal-constant`.

Comment: @glglgl Your statement is correct, but I wasn't trying to argue that this answer doesn't address the key point, simply to offer an idea for improvement.  I just went and looked at the standard, and @starrify copied that section character for charcter; the definition for `digit` is actually in §6.4.2.1 - General Identifiers.

Answer (score -2):

I think it depends on compiler implementation. We have to see the source code to determine whether it flags a "0" constant as octal or not. I can define the non-octal reason in this way: Octals has "0" prefix. But there is no prefix. If the constant is 00, then it IS octal - "octal Zero" :)

Comment: It doesn't depend on the compiler's implementation. It's defined  in the standard as an octal constant. See the other answers.

Comment: You can read answers above: "...Interestingly enough, from that grammar:
•0 is decimal
•but 00 is octal"

Comment: You do understand though that the answers all say that whether or not `0` is octal is *not* implementation dependent. It's defined in the standard as an octal constant.