# Does size_t foo = 0; need a cast?

Tags: c, type-conversion, misra

[Looking at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11310578/1270789) and knowing that [0 is an octal constant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6895543/1270789):

> For hexadecimal *[constants [and octal according to the comments]]*, it is the first type the value can fit in: `int`, `unsigned int`, `long`, `unsigned long`, `long long`, `unsigned long long`

Therefore, I deduce this does not need a cast:

```
size_t foo = 0;
```

However, due to a strict MISRA-C lint tool, I get back a message about an illegal implicit type conversion - MISRA-C:2004 Rule 10.1.

Is my understanding wrong, or is the tool in error?

(NB: I've changed to `size_t foo = 0U;` as that is a lot simpler than arguing with QA, but I'd like to satisfy my own curiosity.)

Comment: How do you define to "need a cast"? There's an implicit conversion, and MISRA tells you about it.

Comment: Also, since you tagged the question C, and not C++, here's [a question about `0` being octal in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26625311/is-0-an-octal-or-a-decimal-in-c/).

Comment: A decimal constant wouldn't need a cast either; any arithmetic type may be implicitly converted to any other arithmetic type. But `size_t foo = 0U;` may also involve an implicit conversion; `0U` is of type `unsigned int`, which may or may not be the same type as `size_t`. (And if MISRA requires a cast, MISRA is being silly.)

Comment: In this particular case there is no meaningful reason to sacrifice the type-independence of `0` initializer and replace it with a completely unnecessarily type-restricted `0U`. If MISRA requires it, it is back to the drawing board for MISRA.

Comment: @AnT - MISRA C:2012 Rule 10.3 explicity allows *a non-negitive interger constant expression of essentially signed type may be assigned to an object of essentially unsigned type if its value can be represented by that type* which is a standard-ese way of saying you don't need the U :-)

Comment: MISRA-C:2004 does require the U but that has been superseded... and even for 2004 was widely (and reasonably IMHO) deviated!

Comment: IINM it's not even possible to portably write out a `size_t` literal, since the whole point of `size_t` is to alias a type of unknown width...

Comment: @Quentin huh? What is a type of unknown width?

Comment: [`typedef /*implementation-defined*/ size_t;`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t) -- There's no way to know whether to initialize it with `0u`, `0ul` or `0ull`.

Comment: but 0u will always work?  Not sure what your point is. A size_t would have to be assigned (and cast) to a standard size (short, long, long long) before serialized for cross platform use.  (not to int, because int size is platform dependent)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but...

- 0 is of type signed int
- 0U is of type unsigned int

`size_t` requires type `size_t` - and sizes are (usually) unsigned

So for strict compliance `size_t foo = 0U;` although it might be more correct to use `size_t foo = (size_t)0;`

As an aside, discussion as to whether 0 is decimal, octal or anything else is irrelevant... it is still zero.

--

Edit to add:

Although explicit conversion between signed and unsigned was deprecated in MISRA C:2004 (although this was widely deviated), for MISRA C:2012 Rule 10.3 explicitly allows *a non-negative integer constant expression of essentially signed type may be assigned to an object of essentially unsigned type if its value can be represented by that type*

This is a standard-ese way of saying you don't need the U