# How to break a long word inside a div, based on the div's parent width?

Tags: html, css

I want to wrap a long word inside a div that passes the border of the div's parent into a new line.

I have tried the `.wordwrap` solution from this [Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638223/is-there-a-way-to-word-wrap-long-words-in-a-div), but it doesn't solve the problem.

Here is what I have tried:

```css
#parent {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: solid 1px;
  position: relative;
}
#child {
  top: 20px;
  left: 300px;
  border: solid 1px;
  position: absolute;
}
.wordwrap {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  /* CSS3 */
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
  /* Firefox */
  white-space: -pre-wrap;
  /* Opera <7 */
  white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
  /* Opera 7 */
  word-wrap: break-word;
  /* IE */
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child" class="wordwrap">
    asfasfafafsafafasfasfafafasfadvaavasdvavdvsavsvasvsvs
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yusrilmaulidanraji/otps5c66/5/

Comment: How about `asfasfafafsafafasfasfafafasfad<wbr/>vaavasdvavdvsavsvasvsvs`

Comment: @Yusril Maulidan Raji Don't forget to validate the correct answer that helped you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't need all those `white-space`

Instead use

```
.wordwrap { 
  word-break : break-all;
}
```

```css
#parent {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: solid 1px;
  position: relative;
}
#child {
  top: 20px;
  left: 300px;
  border: solid 1px;
  position: absolute;
}
.wordwrap {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child" class="wordwrap">
    asfasfafafsafafasfasfafafasfadvaavasdvavdvsavsvasvsvs
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also use

```
word-break : break-word
```

Check this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1795878/4245446) to see the difference

Comment: Code snippet added to show you directly that it works :)

Comment: well, actually I have tried this one in my JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yusrilmaulidanraji/otps5c66/7/ But I have no clue why it doesn't work

Comment: and also, unfortunately, it doesn't work on FireFox and Edge either.

Comment: The only [_downside_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15137272/6399857) of _word-break: break-all;_ is that the container's edge will break every word on its path, **no matter what size the word has!** _i.e. either giant or small words_

Comment: Ok then. In the end, in my case, not only I used the `word-break : break-all;`, but also I had to add `display: inline-block; white-space: pre-wrap;` as well in order to make it sounds. Thanks anw!

Answer (score 3):

The element where you put the text have **position: absolute**. There is a couple of things you should know when using position: absolute in an element:

- It'll by default **only respect it's content width and height** with a position different than absolute/fixed.
- It'll not consume space in the parent element, so t**he structural size of the parent element will never be affected by it**.
- **You can anchor an element with position: absolute** in the nearest parent with other position than the default *(static)*, with the css properties *(top, right, bottom, left)*.

Therefore **you should either remove the position absolute** from that element, or since you are already using a left property, **define a right property too (ie. *right: 0;*)**

**SNIPPET**

```css
#parent {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: solid 1px;
  position: relative;
}
#child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 0;
  left: 300px;
  border: solid 1px;
}
.wordwrap {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  /* CSS3 */
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
  /* Firefox */
  white-space: -pre-wrap;
  /* Opera <7 */
  white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
  /* Opera 7 */
  word-wrap: break-word
  /* IE */
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child" class="wordwrap">
    Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis...
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update**

If you don't want to compromise the absolute positioned #child div, **by defining *right: 0***, which would also anchor it to the right side of the #parent div, based on [Weedoze's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39657098/6399857), you can in fact use the property ***word-break: break-all;***

However [**it has a downside**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15137272/6399857), every word you have inside #child **will automatically break** **no matter what size they have**, even if they are inside a descendent element!

**SNIPPET**

```css
#parent {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: solid 1px;
  position: relative;
}

#child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 300px;
  border: solid 1px;
  text-align: justify;
}

.wordwrap {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  /* CSS3 */
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
  /* Firefox */
  white-space: -pre-wrap;
  /* Opera <7 */
  white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
  /* Opera 7 */

  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child" class="wordwrap">
    Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis...
    
    With word-break: break-all every word will be broken, even little ones! With word-break: break-all every word will be broken, even little ones! 
  </div>
</div>
```

***I tested this one on Firefox and it worked!*** I couldn't test on Edge or IE because I'm running on Ubuntu and I don't have a virtual machine installed right now :)

But if you really **don't want the little/normal words to be broken, nor a compromised right anchored #child**, and of course if possible, then perhaps would be better to approach this layout with a different solution, **[Pugazh idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39657115/6399857) is not a bad start!**

You could use *float: left; max-width: calc(100% - 300px);* and *box-sizing: border-box;* to get the same results, then **using a *super negative margin-bottom* to pull the rest of #parent's content** to the top. It's a bit *hacky* I know, probably there are better ways to get the same results, but this way you wouldn't need to use *position: absolute* nor *word-break: break-all* in #child)

**SNIPPET**

```css
#parent {
  border: solid 1px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

#child {
  position: relative; /* not really needed, just to be on top for contrast */
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  text-align: justify;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid 1px;
  float: left;
  max-width: calc(100% - 300px);
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  margin-bottom: -1000000%; /* Hack to pull #parent content to the top */
}

.wordwrap {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  /* CSS3 */
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
  /* Firefox */
  white-space: -pre-wrap;
  /* Opera <7 */
  white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
  /* Opera 7 */
  word-wrap: break-word;
  /* IE */
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child" class="wordwrap">
    Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis...
    
    And this little words will not get broken And this little words will not get broken And this little words will not get broken.
    
    Butgiantwordswilldefinitelybreakforsure!
  </div>
   
  This is some content This is some content This is some content This is some content  
  This is some content This is some content This is some content This is some content  
  This is some content This is some content This is some content This is some content 
  This is some content This is some content This is some content This is some content 
  This is some content This is some content This is some content This is some content
  This is some content This is some content This is some content This is some content  
  This is some content This is some content This is some content This is some content
  This is some content This is some content This is some content This is some content 
  This is some content This is some content This is some content This is some content
  This is some content This is some content This is some content This is some content  
  This is some content This is some content This is some content This is some content
  This is some content This is some content This is some content This is some content
  This is some content This is some content This is some content This is some content 
  This is some content This is some content This is some content This is some content
  This is some content This is some content This is some content This is some content  
  This is some content This is some content This is some content This is some content 
  :)
</div>
```

Comment: Well, for the `position:absolute`, I can't remove it for some reasons. However, for the `right:0px`, it could be a strong option. Thanks!

Comment: @YusrilMaulidanRaji  - You don't need to specify a measure type (like px or %) when you're defining property with 0, since 0px is the same 0% or in any other measure type :)

Comment: Didn't know that before. Thanks! :)

Comment: @YusrilMaulidanRaji - Update! :)

Comment: @YusrilMaulidanRaji - _**word-break: break-all** has a_ **[downside](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15137272/6399857)**

Comment: Pneumonoultramicroscopicvolcanoconiosis? Do the words `Bad Voltage` mean something to you? :)

Comment: @Daniel `0px` vs `0%` is rather like ["Is 0 octal or decimal?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26625311/is-0-an-octal-or-a-decimal-in-c): Well, it's... it's 0.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of absolute positioning you can try `margin`. Check below example.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/otps5c66/6/)

```css
#parent {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: solid 1px;
  position: relative;
}
#child {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  border: solid 1px;
}
.wordwrap {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  /* CSS3 */
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
  /* Firefox */
  white-space: -pre-wrap;
  /* Opera <7 */
  white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
  /* Opera 7 */
  word-wrap: break-word;
  /* IE */
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child" class="wordwrap">
    asfasfafafsafafasfasfafafasfadvaavasdvavdvsavsvasvsvs
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: while this seems to be an option, there might be a good reason the OP uses absolute positioning, so the least "destructive" option, I think, is [@Weedoze's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39657098/2037924)

Comment: Yup, I have to use the top-left properties for some reasons though. But thanks for the option!

Answer (score 2):

```html
.wordwrap { 
  word-break : break-all;
}
```

```html
#parent {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: solid 1px;
 }
#child {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  border: solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child" class="wordwrap">
    asfasfafafsafafasfasfafafasfadvaavasdvavdvsavsvasvsvs
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In this case it would be better to use `break-word`

Comment: yeah but in general case break-all is better

Answer (score 0):

You should add this rules to your CSS:

```
#parent {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.wordwrap {
   white-space: no-wrap;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Cheers

Comment: Well, it has a different result though. The text instead is being overlapped by the outside border of the parent. The overlapped text should be wrapped to the newline though.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code.

```css
#parent {
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        border: solid 1px;
        position: relative;
      }
      #child {
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-left: 300px;
        border: solid 1px;
      }
      .word-wrap {
      white-space: pre-wrap;
      word-wrap: break-word;
    }
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="parent">
    <div id="child" class="word-wrap">
      GOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOD!
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
```