# why does this printf print out wrong representation of the number in C?

Tags: c, binary

```
int n = 00000011;
printf("n is: %d\n", n);
```

> x is: 9

Shouldn't it be 3 in decimal?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is 0 a decimal literal or an octal literal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895522/is-0-a-decimal-literal-or-an-octal-literal)

Comment: in C numbers starting with 0 are octal numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`00000011` is the octal value of `9`, you can't use the binary representation directly.

```
Octal 011 -> Decimal 9
```

Only, decimal, octal and hexadecimal representations can be specified, for the decimal representation it's straight forward, for the octal representation you prefix the value with a `0` so `09` would not be valid, and for hex representation you prefix the value with `0x`.

**note**: as commented by **abligh**, you can use the `0b` prefix with `gcc` and `clang` and probably other compilers.

Comment: Actually he's *printing* the decimal value of `n`, but setting `n` to be octal 011, i.e. 9 (in decimal). IE it's the assignment not the printing that is decimal.

Comment: In gcc (and I think other C compilers) you can represent binary constants by `int n = 0b11;` as per https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Binary-constants.html

Comment: @abligh I didn't know that, it's not standard right?

Comment: so for example if I wanted to count the number of bits in a number. Would I represent n as a decimal then? int n = 3 instead of n = 0000011

Comment: @CodeCrack the representation has nothing to do with counting bits.

Comment: @iharob it's a gcc extension, but other compilers (e.g. clang: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html) also support it.

Comment: @iharob I understand but let's say I am counting bits using count += (x & 1); x = x >> 1;. I want to specify 00000011 as input. Would I just pass 3 as decimal input instead then?

Comment: @CodeCrack Yes, or `0x03` hex, or `03` octal.

Comment: @iharob, no the assigment is binary  from an octal literal,  the number in the CPU is in binary, and really looks like 00000000 00000000 00000000 00001001 printf converts that to base 10

Comment: @CodeCrack the important thing to note is that how the number got there in the first place is irrelevant. You could have written `n=0x03;` or `n=3;` or `n=03;` or `n=0b11` (on gcc) or `n=517-514;` - once the value of n has been assigned, it's held in memory. That internal storage is always binary (ones and zeros)

Answer (score 0):

In c number literals  starting with 0*digit*  are base-8.
For binary some compilers allow you to start them with 0b.
else you'll have to manually convert them to hex or octal.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    int n=0b00000011;
    printf ("n is %d\n",n);
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: Note `0b` is a gcc extension which is supported by some other C compilers (e.g. clang), and not part of the C standard.