# 01 invalid token

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.3

Hey been learning python3 for a while.

Came across dictionaries and the dictionary_name.get() method and tried to get a random key value.

The problem:

```
data= {}

data.get('key',1)
```

it works and **returns 1**

But instead if I use `data.get('key',01)` it says invalid token why is that?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837874/invalid-token-when-using-octal-numbers). Octal definition has changed for Python3

Comment: Because `01` isn't a valid token - see https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-3127

Answer (score 5):

In Python 2.x, integer literals starting with `0` were interpreted as octal numbers.  In Python 3.x, octal numbers are written with the prefix `0o` instead.  To avoid that old code changes meaning without any warning, literals starting with just `0` are a syntax error now.