# SyntaxError: invalid token python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem with my Python script. When I run this **Python script**:

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self,student_name,student_id,student_phone):
        self.student_name = student_name
        self.student_id = student_id
        self.student_phone = student_phone

obj = Student("ELizaa",1253251,16165544)

print("student name",obj.student_name,"\nstudent id",obj.student_id,"\nStudent phone",obj.student_phone)
```

It is working fine. I got the expected output. **But** when `student_phone` starting with a `0` (like `0124575`), I get an **error**:

```
obj = Student("ELizaa",1253251,016165544)
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: I presume you want to use a string instead.

Comment: So i have to pass the value in string instead of Number ?

Comment: Yes. Based on the varialbe name 'student phone' I presume you want to store the number as base 10, but with leading zeros. The easiest is to store it as a string in that case.

Comment: Why do you not want it as a string? It's an identifier, it's not like you're going to do any numerical work on it, and you're presumably fixed by the bigger system in what values it can take.

Comment: @roganjosh Just I m curios . Is it possible or not . Based on everyone answer , seems it not possible :)

Comment: No, it isn't because, in the general case, you might come across a system that demands a 6 digit code; what will you do with `000001`? You can `zfill` but it will still be a string

Comment: Those student IDs & phone numbers are numeric strings, they aren't integers: you wouldn't do arithmetic on them (although you might want to sort them). So in your Python code you need to quote them. However, you can read numeric strings without quotes using `input()`, or from a file.

Answer (score 1):

In python3, you couldn't use `016165544` to create an integer variable. It's an octonary number in some other programming language, such as `C`. In Python, you should use `0o16165544` or `0O16165544`.

However, what you want to create is a student ID and phone number, so I suggest that you use `string` instead.

Like this:

```py
obj = Student("ELizaa", "1253251", "016165544")
```

Comment: ok Thanks .. I am noob in python and i m stack every day when i go to write code :(

Comment: `016165544` was a valid octal literal in Python 2, but not in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, adding `0` in front of any number needs an extra

- `x` (for hexadecimal) followed by any number in hex digits range `0-9` or `a-f` or `A-F`.
- `o` (for octal) followed by number(s) in octal digits range `0-7`.

Have a look at below:

```
>>> 0o7
7
>>> 0o71
57
>>> 0o713
459
>>>
>>> 0xa
10
>>> 0xA
10
>>> 0x67
103
>>>
```

> » If you exceed the range or if you don't use `x` | `o` after `0`.

```
>>> 0o8
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    0o8
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
>>> 
>>> 08
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    08
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
>>>
```

> **Suggestion:** If you are still willing to use `0` & want to perform operations on phones (for testing) then you can use the below approach to update the numbers.
>
> Here we will store phone number as string & whenever we will update that, we will remove `0` from front, convert the remaining part into an integer, add (any operation) ant convert back to its original (`0` in front) form & I think it is good.

```
>>> student_phone = "016165544"
>>> 
>>> # Add 3 to this
... 
>>> student_phone = "0" + str(int(student_phone.lstrip("0")) + 3)
>>> 
>>> student_phone
'016165547'
>>>
```

Finally, you can call in this way (as you are already doing in your problem except 2nd one).

```
>>> class Student:
...     def __init__(self, student_name, student_id, student_phone):
...         self.student_name = student_name
...         self.student_id = student_id
...         self.student_phone = student_phone
... 
>>> obj = Student("ELizaa",1253251,16165544)
>>> print("student name",obj.student_name,"\nstudent id",obj.student_id,"\nStudent phone",obj.student_phone)
student name ELizaa 
student id 1253251 
Student phone 16165544
>>> 
>>> obj = Student("ELizaa",1253251,"016165544")                                
>>> print("student name",obj.student_name,"\nstudent id",obj.student_id,"\nStudent phone",obj.student_phone)
student name ELizaa 
student id 1253251 
Student phone 016165544
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting a number with the digit 0 makes it an octal number, but the behavior has some nuance. See this solution: [Invalid Token when using Octal numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837874/invalid-token-when-using-octal-numbers)

Comment: Thank you dear <3 .. I got the idea .. But if i want to start with 0 without passing it as string . Is it possible ?

Comment: @ElizaMeww I think you couldn't. :) Student id is a integer-like variable, but it actually should be a string type in your scene.

Comment: Probably. Before we go down that path, why do you want to start it with a 0?